# NestJS MongoDB nested object schema

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, typegoose

I am currently running the code :

```js
export class SystemInformationContent {
  createdAt: number;

  createdBy: User | mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId | null;

  updatedAt?: number;

  updatedBy?: User | mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId | null;
}

@Schema()
export class SystemInformation {
  @Prop(
    raw({
      createdAt: { type: Number, required: true },
      createdBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      updatedAt: { type: Number, default: 0 },
      updatedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        default: null,
      },
    }),
  )
  system: SystemInformationContent;
}
```

I did not found any way of "extending" the schema of `SystemInformationContent` and so used the `raw()` function in the `@Prop()` decorator, but I am wondering if there is a way to do something like this:

```js
export class SystemInformationContent {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  createdAt: number;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })
  createdBy: User | mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId | null;

  @Prop({ default: 0 })
  updatedAt?: number;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', default: null })
  updatedBy?: User | mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId | null;
}

@Schema()
export class SystemInformation {
  @Prop(???)
  system: SystemInformationContent;
}
```

I did not found anything working to put into the `SystemInformation.system` `@Prop()` that take in account the schema of `SystemInformationContent`.

Do you guys know if there is an other way than the `raw` or if I am missing something ?

Edit: All classes of my NestJS application are extending SystemInformation so they all look like :

```json
{
  ...,
  system: {
    createdAt: 1616778310610,
    createdBy: "605e14469d860eb1f0641cad",
    editedAt: 0,
    createdBy: null,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution !

I edited `SystemInformationContent` to :

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { User } from '~/schemas/user.schema';

@Schema({ _id: false })
export class SystemInformationContent {
  @Prop({ type: Number, required: true })
  createdAt: number;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })
  createdBy: User;

  @Prop({ type: Number, default: 0 })
  updatedAt?: number;

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    default: null,
  })
  updatedBy?: User;
}

export const SystemInformationContentSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(
  SystemInformationContent,
);
```

Then in SystemInformation I edited to :

```js
import { Prop, Schema } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import {
  SystemInformationContent,
  SystemInformationContentSchema,
} from '~/schemas/systemInformationContent.schema';

@Schema()
export default class SystemInformation {
  @Prop({ required: true, type: SystemInformationContentSchema })
  system: SystemInformationContent;
}
```

Now everything is working, I used the `@Schema({ _id: false })` to remove the ID generated by the SchemaFactory so I end up with that in the DB :

```json
{
  ...,
  "system": {
    "updatedBy": null,
    "updatedAt": 0,
    "createdAt": 1616847116986,
    "createdBy": {
      "$oid": "605f210cc9fe3bcbdf01c95d"
    }
  },
  ...,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `typegoose` (7.0 or later), then what you currently have should be enough, if you have `emitDecoratorMetadata` enabled in the tsconfig

example with typegoose (the code below uses option extensions from ~7.4):

```
export class SystemInformationContent {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  createdAt: number;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: () => User })
  createdBy: Ref<User>;

  @Prop({ default: 0 })
  updatedAt?: number;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: () => User }) // default is "undefined"
  updatedBy?: Ref<User>;
}

export class SystemInformation {
  @Prop() // thanks to "emitDecoratorMetadata" no explicit types are needed 
  system: SystemInformationContent;

  // but if wanting to do explicit types
  @Prop({ type: () => SystemInformationContent })
  system: SystemInformationContent;
}
```

PS: i dont know where your function `raw` comes from, but this is not an typegoose function

Comment: Hi, am using NestJS that use their own implementation of type goose (https://github.com/kpfromer/nestjs-typegoose)
Thanks a lot for the answer I will look into it !

Comment: I tried your solution, and it did not work, the `emitDecoratorMetadata` is enabled but I think the NestJS typegoose does not work that way...

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, this is what you want. You only missed the `@Schema()` annotation for `SystemInformationContent` and need to inherit this schema where ever you want to. I had a similar problem. So, if this is not what you asked for, please let me know.

```
@Schema()
export class SystemInformationContent {
  // put your @Prop() attributes here, that need to be available in every other schema
}

@Schema()
export class SystemInformation extends SystemInformationContent {
  // no need to do anything else here
  // the attributes are inherited from SystemInformationContent 
}
```

Comment: Hey man, this wasn't the solution I was looking for, but for some reason, your answer unlocked something in my head that made me found the solution, many thanks !